# Passing a searchterm from webapp show results

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a custom function that works searching Drive. I am trying to get the web app to pass the searchterm to the custom function and return the results.

Currently, when I test the function in the logger it works and returns the files.

In the example below I have a hello world working- but as mentioned earlier I haven't been able to pass the searchterm from the input form.

**CODE.GS**

```js
function SearchFiles() {

var searchterm ="'YOUR SEARCHTERM'";  // this would be the variable that is passed from the form on index.html
var searchFor ="title contains " + searchterm;
var owneris ="and 'emailaddress@goeshere.com' in Owners";
var names =[];
var fileIds=[];
  Logger.log(searchFor + " " + owneris);
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor + " " + owneris);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
  fileIds.push(fileId);
  var name = file.getName();
  names.push(name);

}

for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
Logger.log(names[i]);
Logger.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileIds[i]);

}
}

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Hello World')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function parseDataFromAppscript()
{
  return "Hello World!";
}

function processForm(formObject) {
Logger.log('I was called!');
 // here is where I would like to display results of searchterm.
}
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function displayMessage()
    {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(helloWorld).parseDataFromAppscript();
    }

    function helloWorld(stringText)
    {
    document.writeln(stringText);    
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="search">   
    <input type="button" value="submitButton" name="submitButton" onclick="displayMessage()"/>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to your input text box, then use the DOM to get the value.  Put the search term in the parenthesis of the gs function being called.

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function displayMessage() {
        var searchTerm;

        searchTerm = document.getElementById('idSrchTerm').value;

        console.log('searchTerm: ' + searchTerm );
        google.script.run
        .processForm(searchTerm);
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="idSrchTerm" name="search">   
    <input type="button" value="submitButton" name="submitButton" onclick="displayMessage()"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.GS**

```js
function SearchFiles() {
var searchTerm = "";
var searchFor ="title contains " + searchTerm;
var owneris ="and 'youremail@youremail.com' in Owners";
var names =[];
var fileIds=[];
  Logger.log(searchFor + " " + owneris);
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor + " " + owneris);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
  fileIds.push(fileId);
  var name = file.getName();
  names.push(name);
  var endResult, fromSearchingFiles;

  fromSearchingFiles = SearchFiles(searchTerm);//Run SearchFiles function
  //and pass the search term to the function

  endResult = parseDataFromAppscript(fromSearchingFiles);

  return endResult;

}

for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
Logger.log(names[i]);
Logger.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileIds[i]);

}
}

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Hello World')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}



function processForm(searchTerm) {
  var resultToReturn;
  Logger.log('processForm was called! ' + searchTerm);
   // here is where I would like to display results of searchterm.

  resultToReturn  = SearchFiles(searchTerm);

  Logger.log('resultToReturn: ' + resultToReturn)

  return resultToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy, this looks really close- however I am seeing no change when I press the Submit button.  It's like the button does not function.

Comment: Where does my searchFiles function come into play, it appears you have made one as well?

Comment: Now after looking at the console it is giving me a exceeded maximum stack error

Comment: You will need to go through a process of checking how far the code is getting before failing.  You will need to add more `console.log()` statements in the client code, and more `Logger.log()` statements in the server code.  Also, use the VIEW menu, and check the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT to see of the code is completing or failing.  Also, stop the code so that it doesn't run all the way.  Put in a statement: `die()` right before the `google.script.run.function()` line and see if it gets to that point.  There is no function named `die()` so there will be a fatal error.  That's intentional.

Comment: Hi Sandy, thanks for your help! I have updated your code above and am getting close. It does get past google.script.run Now I am seeing an error in the console. Have any idea what this may be? Uncaught Error: Invalid argument: q
 at SearchFiles (Code:9) (SearchWebApp) feb6332e-6f96-4300-bcb3-00b5ff9f58f0
 at processForm (Code:47) (SearchWebApp) feb6332e-6f96-4300-bcb3-00b5ff9f58f0

Comment: It seems that you are making progress, and know what generally needs to be done.  It's just a matter of debugging the details at this point.  I'm not sure what the argument "q" is.

Comment: Hi Sandy I am very close to making this work- still having a few issues- sent you an email if you are able to help. Thanks again.